# Magento generate Barcode using Zend Barcode

Tags: magento-1.9, barcode

I'm struggling with barcode generation of Zend framework. 
My goal is generating a barcode image then save to product image while saving products.

I'm not sure my code is correct and I have no idea how to save rendered barcode into product image attribute **product_barcode_unit**

Please can any help me figure out it ?. I really appreciate your helps.

UPDATE:
I currently can generate barcode image while saving product, I used event catalog_product_save_before. But I cannot save barcode image to product gallery images because of this error:

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   /srv/magento/foodexporta/production/www/devnew/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Attribute/Backend/Media.php
>   on line 329

Here is my code trigger in event:

```
public function generateBarcode($observer)
    {
        $_product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();    
        $_params = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParams();
        $data = $_params['product'];
        if(isset($data['product_barcode_unit'])){
            $barcodeString = (strlen($data['product_barcode_unit']) > 12) ? substr($data['product_barcode_unit'], 0, 12) : $data['product_barcode_unit'] ;
            // Only the text to draw is required
            $barcodeOptions = array('text' => $barcodeString);

            // No required options
            $rendererOptions = array();

            // Draw the barcode in a new image,
            // send the headers and the image
            $barcodeImage = Zend_Barcode::draw(
                'ean13', 'image', $barcodeOptions, $rendererOptions
            );

            $path = Mage::getBaseDir('media').DS."Barcode".DS.$_product->getId()."-barcode-unit-".$barcodeString.".png";

            $store_image = imagepng($barcodeImage,$path);

            if($store_image)
            {
                try {
                    $_product->addImageToMediaGallery($path, 'product_barcode_unit', true, false);
                    $_product->save();
                } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e){
                    Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
        return $this;
    }
```

I'm really grateful for your help. 
.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below code. **Create Barcode directory in media folder**.

```
$file = Zend_Barcode::draw('code128', 'image', array('text' => $barcodeString), array());
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(<ProductId>);
$barcode_path="Barcode/".$product->getId().".png";
$store_image = imagepng($file,Mage::getBaseDir('media').$barcode_path);
if($store_image)
{

    $path = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . $barcode_path;

    $product->addImageToMediaGallery($path, 'image', true, false);
    $product->save();
}
```

Comment: I really appreciate your answer,  it helped me so much to solve my issue.

Comment: For now, I can generate barcode image but cannot save to product image attribute, do you have any ideas ?

Comment: @HungDQ `$product->setBarcodeInnerImage($barcode_path);` by this you are saving path of image. `echo $product->getBarcodeInnerImage()` use this to get bar code image path. I am assuming here that you have created `barcode_inner_image` attribute for product

Comment: it's image attribute that show in gallery images of product. I'm dealing with addImageToMediaGallery function but still struggling.

Comment: @HungDQ check updated answer

Comment: Thank for your upgrade, but anytime I tried save product image, then get this error:
 Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /srv/magento/foodexporta/production/www/devnew/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Attribute/Backend/Media.php on line 329

In case I turn off developer mode, I still got error.

Comment: I've just updated my function is the question.

Comment: @HungDQ why you have added `product_barcode_unit`? Just write `image` because that parameter is for image type like image ,thumb-line and small image .